# Nulls and the MERGE statement: I need to set a value to infinity. How?

Tags: sql-server, merge, null

In SQL Server with a `MERGE` code, everything is fine except when there are 2 nullable columns.

If I pass a null value and the target isn't null, MERGE doesn't see a difference (evals against null = false). If I use IsNull on both sides (source & target) that works, but has the issue of potentially mis-evaluating a value.

What I mean by the last statement is, if I say:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT (IsNull(tgt.C, 0) = IsNull(src.C, 0)) THEN
```

then if tgt.C is null and src.C = 0, no update will be performed. No matter what substitute value I choose, I'll have this problem.

I also tried the "AND NOT (...true...)" syntax since BOL states that evaluations against null result in FALSE. However, it seems they actually result in NULL and do not result in my multi-part statement becoming false.

I thought one solution is to use NaN or -INF or +INF since these are not valid in target. But I can't find a way to express this in the SQL.

Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:

The following logic solves the problem, but it's verbose and won't make for fast evals:

```
declare @i int, @j int

set @j = 0
set @i = 0

if ISNULL(@i, 0) != ISNULL(@j, 0) OR 
    ((@i is null or @j is null) and not (@i is null and @j is null))
    print 'update';
```

Comment: I would like to ask anyone who reads this to upvote this missing ISO feature of MSSQL: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate

Comment: I know this is old, but the MERGE statement is not as old as the statements in your nucleotides. Just leaving this here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In SQL Server 2022 you can use

```
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.C IS DISTINCT FROM src.C
```

In previous versions you can use

```
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (SELECT tgt.C EXCEPT SELECT src.C)
```

The second version can still be more compact if you need to do this check across multiple columns.

```
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (SELECT tgt.A, tgt.B, tgt.C 
                         EXCEPT 
                         SELECT src.A, src.B, src.C)
```

See [this article](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html) for more on this issue.

Comment: This is really a great approach. It actually LOOKS good in my code. Reads something like "when matched and a change exists in these fields of source vs target data"

Comment: EXCEPT and INTERSECT documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

Answer (score 19):

You can change the ON part of the merge statement, putting in a check for when both source and target are null.

```
MERGE tgt
USING src
ON ( -- enter non-nullable columns to match on ...
    tgt.A = src.A
    AND (tgt.C = src.C OR (tgt.C IS NULL AND src.C IS NULL))
)
WHEN MATCHED -- ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, this works better. Just add another substitution value as an OR :-

```
WHEN MATCHED AND 
    ( 
    NOT (IsNull(tgt.C, 0) = IsNull(src.C, 0)) OR NOT (IsNull(tgt.C, 1) = IsNull(src.C, 1)) 
    ) 
THEN ....
```

Comment: Brilliant! Very obvious now that I see it.

Comment: I've added this the booklet I'm compiling on things to know about SQL Server. :)

Comment: Fab, I'm new to this site, so I'm glad that you're the first person I've helped. :) :)
Do let me know when the booklet is finished. There's huge gaps in my knowledge....!

Comment: This worked until the nullable column is a uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 2):

```
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.c <> src.c OR tgt.c IS NULL AND src.c IS NOT NULL OR tgt.c IS NOT NULL AND src.c IS NULL
```

Comment: That will perform a needless update if both src & tgt are null.

Comment: Isn't there a way to say INF?

Comment: "WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.c <> src.c OR ((tgt.c IS NULL OR src.c IS NULL) AND NOT (tgt.c IS NULL AND src.c IS NULL))" works, but what a mess.

Comment: @IanC: yes it is a mess. `PostgreSQL` supports `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` and `MySQL` supports `NOT <=>` (both of which treat `NULL` as distinct comparable values), but `SQL Server` has nothing like that.

Comment: @IanC: `SQL Server` does not support `Inf`. You can pick any other value that is out of your domain; but if you don't have one, you will need to use the ternary logic (the `NULL` mess).

Comment: Well, one can tell SQL Server to do this by turning ANSI NULLS off, but that breaks SQL-92 compliance and the ability is being deprecated. Doing so makes it behave the same as PostgreSQL & MySQL.
It's impossible to say infinity?? Crazy.

Comment: @Quassnoi I have decided rather to alter the domain and disallow the nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Have  you tried `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, which will make `NULL=NULL` return true?  [This may create additional issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) but it could be a script-level workaround (turn it off then on once you run your proc).

Comment: BOL advises that ANSI NULLS are being deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

This works as well and may be better when you have multiple columns that you want to check if they are different.

```
  MERGE @t2 a

  using @t1 b

  ON a.PK = b.PK

  WHEN MATCHED AND CHECKSUM(a.PK,a.VALUE)!= CHECKSUM(b.pk,b.VALUE)

  THEN UPDATE SET a.VALUE = b.VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for null in the ON Clause:

```
MERGE TargetTable
USING (VALUES (0)) as s(x)
ON last_run is not null
WHEN not matched then
insert (last_run) values(getdate())
when matched then
update set last_run=getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 0 when the values are null, why not use a value that is highly unlikely to exist?
EG (IsNull(tgt.C, 2093128301).

The datatypes are int so you have a lot to play with......

Comment: I thought of that... the problem is almost any number could be in the domain. Even if I did -0.0000000001... that still has some element of risk.

Comment: In that case, use the value you substitute in the clause too, eg :-

Comment: WHEN MATCHED AND (NOT (IsNull(tgt.C, 123456789) = IsNull(src.C, 123456789)) OR (tgt.C = 123456789 AND src.C ! = 123456789) OR (tgt.C ! = 123456789 AND src.C = 123456789) THEN or something similar or more elegant, as this is getting messy too.... :(

Answer (score -1):

```
WHEN MATCHED AND
(
   NULLIF(tgt.C, src.C) IS NOT NULL OR NULLIF(src.C, tgt.C) IS NOT NULL
)
THEN
```