# How to handle the null in merge SQL's WHEN MATCHED?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
MERGE TARGET T
USING SOURCE S
ON T.ID=S.ID

WHEN MATCHED AND (S.NAME<>T.NAME OR S.DOB<>T.DOB)
THEN UPDATE
SET T.NAME=S.NAME, T.DOB=S.DOB;
```

The above is not able to handle situation where name/dob is null on source or target side. Because comparisons with NULL return false. How to handle this?

Example:

```
COALESCE(S.NAME,'')<>COALESCE(T.NAME,'')
```

Or

```
COALESCE(S.NAME,0)<>COALESCE(T.NAME,0)
```

Or

```
NULLIF(S.NAME,'')<>NULLIF(T.NAME,'')
```

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question? What do you actually want to know?

Comment: which of the approaches is good? Or for example is it better to write `COALESCE(S.NAME,0)` instead of `COALESCE(S.NAME,'')`?

Comment: Which one works as you desire?

Comment: Don't all almost do the same thing? I'm really confused which 1 to choose so looking for some guidance here please.

Comment: Choose the one that works ..

Comment: Use the first or second. The last one is wrong. Depending on the data type, if it is string type, `COALESCE(col, '')` or numeric then `COALESCE(col,0)`

Comment: For a date column can I use COALESCE(col, '')?

Comment: @variable `''` is not a valid `date` value, so no.

Comment: it would default to 1900-01-01 so why not?

Comment: @variable Relying on `'' == 1901-01-01` is bad practice, imo - and anyway: `1901-01-01` is not the same thing as a `NULL` value in a `date` column.

Comment: Can you recommend what is good practice for Date?

Comment: @variable I already have, **in my answer (posted 30 minutes ago)**. My answer works for all data-types and `NULL`-ability. Is there any good reason for your seeming _allergy_ to using `EXCEPT`?

Comment: Obligatory: [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge)

Answer (score 5):

- [Use `EXISTS( SELECT src.* EXCEPT SELECT tgt.* )` to detect if the source row differs from the target row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509722/nulls-and-the-merge-statement-i-need-to-set-a-value-to-infinity-how) in `MERGE INTO` statements.
- In T-SQL, `EXCEPT` **does** sucuessfully compare `NULL` values, and `NULL` with `NOT NULL` values, whereas (as you've noticed) the `=` and `<>` operators do not.

  - Another alternative is to use `IS DISTINCT FROM` for each column, [however SQL Server does not (yet) support this feature](https://modern-sql.com/concept/null).
- Don't forget to also specify `WITH HOLDLOCK`. [It's very important with `MERGE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187776/merge-deadlocking-prevention).

Like so:

```sql
MERGE INTO destTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS tgt
USING srcRelation AS src ON
    /* Only specify PK columns here: */
    tgt.Pk1 = src.Pk1
    AND
    tgt.Pk2 = src.Pk2

WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (

    /*
    Only specify "data" columns here; these are the columns which are also included in the UPDATE SET clause below.
    Don't include GENERATED, rowversion, PRIMARY KEY, and other "non-data" columns
    */

    SELECT tgt.Col1, tgt.Col2, tgt.Col3, etc
    EXCEPT
    SELECT src.Col1, src.Col2, src.Col3, etc
)
THEN UPDATE SET
    tgt.Col1 = src.Col1,
    tgt.Col2 = src.Col2,
    tgt.Col3 = src.Col3

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN etc...;
```

Specifically, in your case:

```sql
MERGE INTO "target" WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS tgt
USING "source" AS src ON
    tgt."ID" = src."ID"
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (
    SELECT tgt."Name"
    EXCEPT
    SELECT src."Name"
)
THEN UPDATE SET
    tgt."Name" = src."Name";
```

Comment: Does COALESCE not cover any scenario that is covered by your code example?

Comment: @variable As others have pointed out in their comment-replies already: **`COALESCE` is inappropriate in this case** because it doesn't indicate that `''` is distinct from `NULL`, not to mention introducing other ambiguities w.r.t. data-types. Point is: **you should not** use `COALSECE` (nor `ISNULL`) in a `MERGE ... WHEN MATCHED AND...` clause. - whereas `EXISTS ( SELECT src... EXCEPT SELECT tgt... )` is idiomatic in T-SQL and _works as-expected_.

Comment: @variable and using `coalesce` can result in the query being unsargable i.e. unable to use indexes. Hence this is a better solution. (You did ask for the best way to do it :) )